# Retrieving CharOffset from TextPointer

Tags: c#

I have this sequence in a RichTextBox: A**B**AC**A**DEF

I would like the user to hover over the sequence and for me to be able to know that they are looking at the Nth character in the sequence. If the user hovers over C I should get 4.

I have started with this code:

```
Point mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(richTextBox);
TextPointer position = richTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint(mousePosition, true);
int offset = richTextBox.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(position);
```

However, I cannot use GetOffsetToPosition(position); on the richTextBox as the text contains formatting so offsets don't match the values I expect. For instance instead of C returning 4 it might return 8 due to the formatting on the B. I would like to get the offset that ignores formatting.

I can see from debugging that TextPointer contains the member variable "CharOffset" which matches the value I want returned by position. However, I can't get access to it as far as I can see. Is there a method to access this value somewhere that I have missed or do I have to do this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came here looking for an answer where I didn't need to use Reflection. However, seeing no answer, here's the answer using Reflection.

```cs
public static class TextPointerExtensions
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo CharOffestProperty = typeof(TextPointer).GetProperty("CharOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    public static int GetCharOffsetUsingReflection(this TextPointer textPointer)
    {
        return (int)CharOffestProperty.GetValue(textPointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading the [TextPointer.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Documents/TextPointer.cs), I also think the reflection is the best way to get the `CharOffset`

Comment: @Hanabi Using reflection to access private or internal members especially those of a library or framework only leads to very fragile code. Those members are not public for a reason. You must expect that they change any time for example when the owner fixes bugs, refactors his code like renaming members or moving/removing/replacing members, redesigns the implementation or even worse changes the functionality etc. There are plenty of reasons why internal code can change between versions. Those changes are silent and potentially breaking changes as they don't affect the API...