# How to get highlighted text's absolute position and length of RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

In WPF project, I use `RichTextBox` to show highlighted text, like below.

> **Hello**, this is **Tom** Xue, nice to meet you.

Let's assume **Hello** and **Tom** are both highlighted with color `Brushes.Yellow`.

And I need to get their absolute start index and length, that is `0,5` and `15,3`. With these data, I can reconstruct this rich text.

Any advise?

Comment: maybe this helps ? [charoffset-from-textpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633776/retrieving-charoffset-from-textpointer)

Comment: What is the scenario? When you select the text to highlight it then you already know the meta info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextPointer` class along with the `GetPropertyValue` method. Consider the `MainRichTextBox` in the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // ... some text and highlighting initialization ...
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int getRenderedIndex(TextPointer pointer)
            {
                return new TextRange(
                    MainRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                    pointer
                ).Text.Length;
            }

            var highlightedSegments = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            int highlightStartIndex = -1;
            TextPointer current = MainRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart;
            while (current != null)
            {
                TextPointer next = current.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                if (next != null && (new TextRange(current, next).GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty) as SolidColorBrush)?.Color == Colors.Yellow)
                {
                    if (highlightStartIndex < 0)
                        highlightStartIndex = getRenderedIndex(current);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (highlightStartIndex >= 0)
                        highlightedSegments.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(highlightStartIndex, getRenderedIndex(current) - highlightStartIndex));
                    highlightStartIndex = -1;
                }

                current = next;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", highlightedSegments));
        }
    }
}
```

In the given code, we traversed the `Document` property of the `RichTextBox` and attempted to locate highlighted segments. The crucial point lies in the `getRenderedIndex` inner function, which returns the index of the input pointer based on the textual representation.

Finally, upon clicking the button, the highlighted segments will be displayed:

[image]

Comment: This won't work for a more complex document that is composed of multiple inline elements. For example GetNextContextPosition may return the wrong context.

Comment: I think that in more complex documents, the textual representation index doesn't have any meaning. However, could you please provide an example and discuss it, so I can test my solution using that?

Comment: Why do you believe that the index of a complexly composed document is not relevant? From the "outside" you still see a simple formatted text. I will post an answer later.